# How to use dynamic cast with variadics?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a working functor_wrapper class for 2 parameters that I'm having trouble generalising into variadic template parameters.

In particular, I'm having trouble getting the syntax right while converting this line in 2 parameters to variadics:

**2 Parameter CODE**

```
return m_cb( dynamic_cast<T const&>( t ), dynamic_cast<U const&>( u ));
```

**Broken Variadic CODE**

```
return m_cb( dynamic_cast<I const&>( t ), 
                            dynamic_cast<typename... const& Cs>( u... ));
```

For anyone who wants to know, this wrapper class is part of a multiple_dispatch class.  In order to provide a common type/interface to the client, I have this Functor_Wrapper class and operator() that takes the parent class type.  When dispatching, I downcast by `dynamic_cast<>`ing the parameters down to the correct types.

**UPDATE**

I just realised that I have another problem:  my virtual operator() in my `Parent_Functor_Wrapper` needs to be converted to n parameters of `P const&` so I need to unroll the signature somehow!

The same applies to the concrete implementation of operator() in `Functor_Wrapper`.

**UPDATE 2**

Posting complete code so the programming context can be better understood.

**UPDATE 3**

Accepting [ildjam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015663/975129) because it addresses the original problem.  I need to think some more about how to deal with the pure virtual operator().  Meanwhile, the code below works fine if you comment out `#define USE_VARIADICS`, and run the hard-coded version.  I will post a separate question if I cannot resolve this issue.

**CODE**

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#define USE_VARIADICS
#ifdef USE_VARIADICS
template<typename P,typename R,typename... Cs>
struct Parent_Functor_Wrapper
{
        using cb_func = std::function<R(P const&, P const& )>;

        virtual R operator()( P const&, P const& ) = 0;
};

// parent class, return type, concrete classes...
template<typename P,typename R,typename I,typename... Cs>
struct Functor_Wrapper :
        public Parent_Functor_Wrapper<P,R,Cs...>
{
        using cb_func = std::function<R(I const&, Cs const& ...)>;
        cb_func  m_cb;

        // dynamic_cast<typename... const& Cs>( u... ) -> dynamic_cast<Cs const&>(u)...
        Functor_Wrapper( cb_func cb ) : m_cb( cb ) { }
        virtual R operator()( P const& t, Cs const& ... u ) override
        {
                return m_cb( dynamic_cast<I const&>( t ), 
                        dynamic_cast<Cs const&>( u )...);
        }
};
#else
template<typename P,typename R>
struct Parent_Functor_Wrapper
{
        using cb_func = std::function<R(P const&, P const& )>;

        virtual R operator()( P const&, P const& ) = 0;
};

template<typename P,typename R,typename T,typename U>
struct Functor_Wrapper :
        public Parent_Functor_Wrapper<P,R>
{
        using cb_func = std::function<R(T const&, U const&)>;
        cb_func  m_cb;

        Functor_Wrapper( cb_func cb ) : m_cb( cb ) { }
        virtual R operator()( P const& t, P const& u ) override
        {
                return m_cb( dynamic_cast<T const&>( t ), dynamic_cast<U const&>( u ));
        }
};
#endif

template<typename T,unsigned N>
struct n_dimension
{
        using type = typename n_dimension<T,N-1>::type;
};

template<typename T>
struct n_dimension<T,1>
{
        using type = std::tuple<T>;
};

template<typename K>
K gen_key( K* p=nullptr, size_t idx=0 )
{
        return *p;
};

template<typename K,typename T,typename... Ts>
K gen_key( K* p=nullptr, size_t idx=0 )
{
        K m_instance;
        if ( p==nullptr )
                p = &m_instance;
        *(p->begin() + idx) = typeid( T ).hash_code();
        gen_key<K,Ts...>( p, ++idx );
        return m_instance;
};

template<typename F,typename P,typename... Cs>
struct multiple_dispatcher { multiple_dispatcher() { } };

template<typename F,typename P,typename I,typename... Cs>
struct multiple_dispatcher<F,P,I,Cs...>
{
        using functor_type = Parent_Functor_Wrapper<P,std::string>;
        using key_type     = std::array<size_t,F::n_dimension::val>;
        using map_type     = std::map<key_type,functor_type*>;
        using value_type   = typename map_type::value_type;

        map_type   m_jump_table;

        multiple_dispatcher( std::initializer_list<value_type> const& cb_mapping )
        {
                for( const auto& p : cb_mapping )
                        m_jump_table.insert( p );
        }

        template< typename T, typename U >
        typename F::return_type operator()( T& x, U& y )
        {
                auto k = key_type{ { x.get_id(), y.get_id() } };
                auto func = m_jump_table.at( k );
                return (*func)( x, y );
        }

        size_t size() const { return m_jump_table.size(); }
};

// =============================================================================

struct A { virtual ~A() { } 
        virtual size_t get_id() const { return typeid( A ).hash_code(); }
};
struct B : public A { virtual ~B() { } 
        virtual size_t get_id() const override { return typeid( B ).hash_code(); }
};
struct C : public A { int x; virtual ~C() { } 
        virtual size_t get_id() const override { return typeid( C ).hash_code(); }
};

struct Functor_Pairs
{
        using return_type = std::string;
        enum n_dimension { val = 2 };

  static std::string MyFn(A const& arg1, A const& arg2) { return "A,A"; }
  static std::string MyFn(A const& arg1, B const& arg2) { return "A,B"; }
  static std::string MyFn(A const& arg1, C const& arg2) { return "A,C"; }
  static std::string MyFn(B const& arg1, A const& arg2) { return "B,A"; }
  static std::string MyFn(B const& arg1, B const& arg2) { return "B,B"; }
  static std::string MyFn(B const& arg1, C const& arg2) { return "B,C"; }
  static std::string MyFn(C const& arg1, A const& arg2) { return "C,A"; }
  static std::string MyFn(C const& arg1, B const& arg2) { return "C,B"; }
  static std::string MyFn(C const& arg1, C const& arg2) { return "C,C"; }
};

// =============================================================================

std::string (*MyFun_aa)(A const&, A const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_ab)(A const&, B const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_ac)(A const&, C const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_ba)(B const&, A const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_bb)(B const&, B const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_bc)(B const&, C const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_ca)(C const&, A const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_cb)(C const&, B const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;
std::string (*MyFun_cc)(C const&, C const&) = &Functor_Pairs::MyFn;

Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,A,A>   w_aa( MyFun_aa );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,A,B>   w_ab( MyFun_ab );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,A,C>   w_ac( MyFun_ac );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,B,A>   w_ba( MyFun_ba );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,B,B>   w_bb( MyFun_bb );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,B,C>   w_bc( MyFun_bc );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,C,A>   w_ca( MyFun_ca );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,C,B>   w_cb( MyFun_cb );
Functor_Wrapper<A,std::string,C,C>   w_cc( MyFun_cc );

// =============================================================================

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
        B  b;
        C  c;

        A& arg1 = b;
        A& arg2 = c;

        using md_type = multiple_dispatcher<Functor_Pairs,A,B,C>;
        using K       = md_type::key_type;

        md_type  md
        {
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,A,A>(), &w_aa ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,A,B>(), &w_ab ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,A,C>(), &w_ac ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,B,A>(), &w_ba ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,B,B>(), &w_bb ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,B,C>(), &w_bc ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,C,A>(), &w_ca ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,C,B>(), &w_cb ),
                std::make_pair( gen_key<K,C,C>(), &w_cc )
        };

        std::cerr << "N = " << md.size() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "RESULT = " << md( arg1, arg2 ) << std::endl;

        assert( !std::string( "B,C" ).compare( md( arg1, arg2 )) );

#if 0
        std::cerr << typeid( A ).hash_code() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << typeid( B ).hash_code() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << typeid( C ).hash_code() << std::endl;
#endif

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typename... const& Cs` -> `Cs const& ...`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm looking at C++ anymore or some advanced alien language.

Comment: @ildjarn `sandbox.cpp:125:26: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘const’`

Comment: If you have C++11, why bother writing a wrapper when there already is [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: Regarding your error message, which line in the shown code is line 125?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg because this wrapper does a dynamic_cast<> - I actually **do** use `std::function` in the code!

Comment: Also, `dynamic_cast` is used to cast from _one_ type to another, I don't think it's possible to use `dynamic_cast` with variable types like that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right - in the general case, you cannot do that.  However, in the context of this multiple-dispatcher code, the `Cs` are expected to be subclasses of `P`, so it works out fine (if you comment out the `#ifdef USE_VARIADICS` in the code above, it will build and run fine for the hard-coded 2-parameter version).

Comment: @JesusRamos That's exactly what I thought the first time I saw C++11 - it takes a while to get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
dynamic_cast<typename... const& Cs>( u... )
```

to:

```
dynamic_cast<Cs const&>( u )...
```

The former (invalid syntax aside) is attempting to expand `Cs` into a single `dynamic_cast` while the latter expands each type in `Cs` into its own `dynamic_cast`.

That being said, I don't think your `override` will work since your base's `operator()` signature is `R operator()( P const&, P const& )` and your derived's signature is not (unless `Cs const&...` coincidentally happens to expand into `P const&`)…

Comment: +1 Yup, that worked!!! TYVM - now, I just need to do that unwrapping of the signature in the **UPDATE**.  I'm scratching my head on that one...  ...yup, you caught my other error - I'm trying to figure out how to convert that signature to `R operator()( P const&... )` now.  I think I need a helper-variadic-template-class that can derive the type/signature.

Comment: @kfmfe04 : Why not just change your base's `operator()` definition from `virtual R operator()( P const&, P const& ) = 0;` to `virtual R operator()( P const&, Cs const& ... ) = 0;`? I don't get the point of `P` in the first place.

Comment: Because it needs a *one common interface* from the client's POV.  This is part of a multiple-dispatch: the operator is supposed to do the dispatch/multiplexing (that's why I need to dynamic-cast parameters down to the real types).  `P` is the parent class of all the possible parameters `Cs`.  `Cs` are concrete subclasses of `P`.  I'll throw up the client code into the OP so this makes sense.